# 2 columns show same data when choosing something from filters on top in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have 2 columns , one of them contains '**Number of employees stopped in the period** 'and the another one  contains ' **Number of employees in Departments**
and when i choose something from filter on the top for ex , between 2 dates (to show me how many employees has stopped and how many employees the departments have in periods),But - afterwards , That column contains '*Number of employees in Departments*' will display same data /numbers as displayed before in '*Number of employees stopped in the period* ' , But thats not i want  , i want display front of each departments how many employees they have and i did but i think in the wrong way.Can someone please point me in the right direction? 
**Preview of table - Updated:**

[image]

**Design of table /repot body - Updated:**

[image]
**Row and Column Groups:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing in both fields of the report the count of Medarbajder.
You could solve it by adding a left join with a sub select query that will have number of employees per department. 
You could get the Nr_Employees_In_Department from that sub select.

The whole query would look like this:

```
 YOUR_EXISTING_QUERY 
 LEFT JOIN
    (
        select p.DepartmentName, count(distinct u.Id) Nr_Employees
        from Paychecks p join Users u on u.Id = p.UserId
        group by p.DepartmenName
     ) totals on totals.DepartmentName = YOUR_EXISTING_QUERY.DepartmentName
```

Comment: tnx for your help rigerta , it's works fine ,But when i get sum of 2 numbers ,for ex Handel Department have 34 employee and IT Department have 22 and sum of 2 numbers is 56 but in report shows 78 . i dont why

Comment: Is 78 the total number of emplyees you have in all departments? 
Did you define a grouping in the tablix, on your report?

Comment: Rigerta , i just update my question with new screenshots as you can se better ,whats going on :)

Comment: No , i dont have it for all departments .. it will be changed depands how many employee work in departments but total of that is not correct number - yes i define a grouping